# Website scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to scrape some data from this html code. More precisly I want to get all numbers (here: [401969217, 401969218]). Of course the html website is longer and more numbers exist.

```
<td class="nw">1. FC Köln</td>
<td class="nw">Hamburger SV</td>
<td class="nw">3 - 7 - 10</td>
<td class="kicktipp-tippabgabe ">
  <input name="spieltippForms[401969217].tippAbgegeben" id="spieltippForms_401969217_tippAbgegeben" value="true" type="hidden"/>
  <input id="spieltippForms_401969217_heimTipp" name="spieltippForms[401969217].heimTipp" type="tel" value="2" size="2" maxlength="3"/>:
  <input id="spieltippForms_401969217_gastTipp" name="spieltippForms[401969217].gastTipp" type="tel" value="2" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="nw kicktipp-time">26.08.17 15:30</td>
  <td class="nw">Bayer 04 Leverkusen</td>
  <td class="nw">1899 Hoffenheim</td>
  <td class="nw">6 - 3 - 10</td>
  <td class="kicktipp-tippabgabe ">
    <input name="spieltippForms[401969218].tippAbgegeben" id="spieltippForms_401969218_tippAbgegeben" value="true" type="hidden"/>
    <input id="spieltippForms_401969218_heimTipp" name="spieltippForms[401969218].heimTipp" type="tel" value="2" size="2" maxlength="3"/>:
    <input id="spieltippForms_401969218_gastTipp" name="spieltippForms[401969218].gastTipp" type="tel" value="2" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="nw kicktipp-time"/>
  ...
```

I was able to scrape all teams by the following method:

```
teams = tree.xpath('//td[@class="nw"]/text()')
```

Unfortunatelly I don`t know how to modify this to solve my new problem. Hope you can help :)

Comment: Seeing as those numbers are within the input and id names, I don't see how lxml or xpath will help you to extract only the numbers themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your xpath expression, you don't want `'//td[@class="nw"]/text()'`, as that gets the values between the tags with `class="nw"` as an attribute.  Instead, based on the html you provided and the desired output, you should try to grab the `name` attribute of the `input` tag and parse that value.

```
from lxml import html
import re

h = html.fromstring('''<table><tr><td class="kicktipp-tippabgabe ">
  <input name="spieltippForms[401969217].tippAbgegeben" id="spieltippForms_401969217_tippAbgegeben" value="true" type="hidden"/>
  <input id="spieltippForms_401969217_heimTipp" name="spieltippForms[401969217].heimTipp" type="tel" value="2" size="2" maxlength="3"/>:
  <input id="spieltippForms_401969217_gastTipp" name="spieltippForms[401969217].gastTipp" type="tel" value="2" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="nw kicktipp-time">26.08.17 15:30</td>
  <td class="nw">Bayer 04 Leverkusen</td>
  <td class="nw">1899 Hoffenheim</td>
  <td class="nw">6 - 3 - 10</td>
  <td class="kicktipp-tippabgabe ">
    <input name="spieltippForms[401969218].tippAbgegeben" id="spieltippForms_401969218_tippAbgegeben" value="true" type="hidden"/>
    <input id="spieltippForms_401969218_heimTipp" name="spieltippForms[401969218].heimTipp" type="tel" value="2" size="2" maxlength="3"/>:
    <input id="spieltippForms_401969218_gastTipp" name="spieltippForms[401969218].gastTipp" type="tel" value="2" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>''')

numbers = [int(x) for e in h.xpath('//input[@type="hidden"]') 
              for x in re.findall(r'\[(\d+)\]', e.get('name'))]

numbers
# returns:
[401969217, 401969218]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the `id`s with the numbers in them is with code like this.

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> tree = html.parse('table.htm')
>>> tree.xpath('.//input[contains(@id,"_heimTipp")]/@id')
['spieltippForms_401969217_heimTipp', 'spieltippForms_401969218_heimTipp']
```

I don't know what kinds of variability is to be found in the values of the `id`s, so it's not easy to say how these should be processed. But it might be as simple as,

```
>>> ids = tree.xpath('.//input[contains(@id,"_heimTipp")]/@id')
>>> numbers = [int(id.split('_')[1]) for id in ids]
>>> numbers
[401969217, 401969218]
```

Comment: Thanks for this additional solution :)  Its really easy to understand and might help me for further problems